# Getting place values of a number w/ modulus?

Tags: javascript, math, division, modulus

- I need to get the place value of a random number submitted by a user.
  This number can by anything from **0-1000000000000000** *(zero to one
  trillion)*.
- I think this can be achieved by using the JavaScript modulus `%`
  operator.  The problem, I don't really know how to use it, nor do I
  understand it.
- **Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RXe8H/2/).**

(All I know is `10%3` returns `1` because `3*3` = `9` and `10-9` = `1`)

I figured out the ones, tens, hundreds, and thousands:

```
var ones = Math.floor(num % 10),
    tens = Math.floor(num / 10 % 10),
    hundreds = Math.floor(num / 100 % 10),
    thousands = Math.floor(num % 10000 / 1000);
```

I *just* need:

1. Ten thousands
2. Hundred thousands
3. Millions
4. Ten millions
5. Hundred millions
6. Billions
7. Ten billions
8. Hundred billions
9. Trillions

-- I don't even know if this is possible for the rest, but if you have any hints or find at least one, let me know!  Thank you.

Comment: "The problem, I don't really know how to use it, nor do I understand it." -- See here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic

Comment: `num.toString(10).split("")`? What do you need the place values for?

Comment: I'm making a number to word translator.

Comment: @Matthew - Before I write out a long answer, can you just confirm that what you're trying to do is accept a numeric value such as 123456789 from the user and output "one hundred twenty-three million four hundred fifty-six thousand seven hundred eighty-nine"?

Comment: @CptRobby -- I appreciate your assistance.  If you look at my answer below, you can see I figured it out!  And yes that is what I am doing, but in Spanish. :)

Comment: @Matthew - Ah. I don't really see how that's the answer exactly (especially since the pattern is inconsistent), but if it works for you, then I guess it's fine. I also don't really know how numbers are read in Spanish, so I won't try LOL. I would suggest you go ahead and accept an answer though so that the question doesn't show up as unanswered. ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
        var ones = Math.floor(num % 10),
            tens = Math.floor(num/10 % 10),
            hundreds = Math.floor(num/100 % 10),
            thousands = Math.floor(num/1000 % 10),
            tenThousands = Math.floor(num / 10000 % 10),
            hundredThousands = Math.floor(num / 100000 % 10),
            millions = Math.floor(num / 1000000 % 10),
            tenMillions = Math.floor(num / 10000000 % 10),
            hundredMillions = Math.floor(num / 100000000 % 10);
```

Managed to get to 100  million.

Comment: I can't edit, but I believe the fourth line is supposed to be:
`thousands = Math.floor(num / 1000 % 10)`

Answer (score 0):

```
var scaleStepWidth = 0;
var number = Math.ceil(1052220420.32);
var placeValue = 1;
for(i=0;i<(number.toString().length-1);i++){
    placeValue *= 10;
}
scaleStepWidth = eval(number.toString()[0])*placeValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

The modulus function finds the remainder in division.

For example:

`9 % 5 = 4` because the remainder from `9 / 5` is `4`

Then we can construct a function to find any place value in a number. (This is all in regular Math because I'm not familiar with JavaScript but it's probably a smooth conversion)

`GetDigit(x,y) = floor(mod(x/(10^floor(y)-1),10))`

In Python it's:

```
import math
def GetDigit(x, y):
    return math.floor((x/((10^math.floor(y))-1)) % 10)
```

I know it's an old question but I couldn't see any other answers giving a definitive function.

Answer (score 0):

Insted of declaring varaibles for all the places, this solution would give us an array of all the places

```js
arr = [];
n = 39998989898989898 // your number here
m = 10;
while (n > 0) {
  i = n % m;
  arr.push(i);
  n -= i;
  m = m * 10;
}
console.log(arr);
```

This can work for more than one trillion